# Ruby On Rails Installation in FreeBSD OS -Error in libv8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, freebsd, bundle-install

Am using FreeBSd OS , When i try to install libv8,

```
gem install libv8
```

its throwing an error ...

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby18 extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby18
extconf.rb:13: uninitialized constant Gem (NameError)
Checking for Python...


extconf.rb:13: uninitialized constant Gem
```

I have icluded

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'libv8', '3.3.10.4'
```

in gem file ..

Comment: @shingara can you see any issue?

Comment: have you install the node.js on your freeBSD ?

Comment: @shingara..No hw it can be done..

Comment: @shingara. S done ... now node is installing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen in Ruby 1.8.7 which doesn't automatically include ruby gems like 1.9.x does. There is an update in github here: https://github.com/fractaloop/libv8/blob/master/ext/libv8/extconf.rb

But this doesn't seem to be in the published gem at this time. It *should* be as easy as installing like this:

```
gem 'libv8', :git => 'git://github.com/fractaloop/libv8.git'
```

But from looking at the source, it dynamically associates the gem version with a version of the v8 library, and when i tried it, it failed, saying it was version 0.0.4. I'm on a different OS though, so try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: For others looking into this, execjs works with other javascript runtimes. If you can't get rubyracer/libv8 working, try node.js out. This works a lot easier for me using OpenIndiana/OpenSolaris.